# How do I get emoji autosuggestions on iOS 11 keyboards

Tags: ios, ios11

Prior to updating to iOS 11, app keyboards used to show emoji suggestions above the keyboard as I typed into a UITextField (for example). This still happens in the iMessages app for example (and the slack app). Is this now a setting I need to set in code?

Comment: If you press the globe button on the bottom, can you actually select the Emoji keyboard?
I have the same problem - since the update, my app only allows latin characters, no emoji or other alphabets :(

Comment: @AlexRuyven I figured it out i think — the suggestions reset on the update (or new phone maybe), but as you use emojis in specific apps a bit more, the emoji suggestions come back :)

Comment: Ah okay! It also seems to be app specific, e.g. I have one emoji that I always replace in my Messenger app and it still works there, but not in other apps. If you want, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question ;)
My other problem was because of a third party framework (Eureka, specifically NameRow), so unless you're using that, all keyboards work. Another problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think — the suggestions reset on the update (or new phone maybe), but as you use emojis in specific apps a bit more, the emoji suggestions come back